# How do i increase fetching of Instagram data in PHP

Tags: php, html, json, instagram

On the Explore.php page i need to display the Instagram username with Profile picture, and followers and i use Instagram.php Page which uses JSON to fetch the data. I have added various functions in Instagram.php to fetch followers, likes, bio, media of Instagram username.

In the Explore.php i used the following code to print data in HTML TABLE

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ig_accounts WHERE confirmed = 1 LIMIT $limit, $rows_per_page";
$run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query))
{
$user_name = $rows['username'];
?>
<tr>
<td><img src="<?php echo profile_pic($user_name); ?>" width="30" height="30"  class="img-circle"><a href="accounts.php?username=<?php echo $user_name?>">@<?php echo $user_name; ?> </a></td>
<td> <?php echo (followers($user_name))/1000; echo "k"; ?></td>
<td> $<?php echo $rows['account_amount']; ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php   
}
```

This code works, but takes too long to process and print the data on Explore.php page, and sometimes i get 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR due to timeout.
Is there anyway to boost the processing of the code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the timout limit in your php.ini file.

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
; or whatever size you want

max_execution_time = 60
; also, higher if you must - sets the maximum time in seconds
```

You could also use paging or use an infinite scroll. You can google it there is a lot of tutorials.

Comment: i have already added upload_max_filesize = 12M and also paging is present on the explore page, what i want is to increase the execution speed and not the timeout for it :) well thanks for it. appreciate your help